# Sorting. Django

Tags: django

Suppose i want to sort my entries in queryset by sum (or some formula) of two or more field.

for example:

```
  sorted_artikles=Article.all().sort_by('sum_of_rating+user_vetes+user_readed')



example model:

    Class Article(models.Model):
        text=CharField()
        author=ForeinKey()
        user_voted=IntegerField()
        rating=IntegerField()
        user_readed=IntegerField()
```

Should i subclass method order_by() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You should use the `select` and `order_by` arguments of the [`QuerySet.extra()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method.

Comment: ... Does no one bother reading the docs they get pointed to any more? `SomeModel.objects.extra(select={'fieldsum': 'field1 + field2 + field3'}, order_by=['fieldsum'])`